# Forward Converter - Voltage through primary winding Question

Tags: power, converter

[image]

So my waveform is a step function, where maximum voltage is at Vin = 40V, and minimum voltage is (-N1/N3)*Vin = -200V. The minimum voltage doesn't sound right to me, so I was wondering if anyone can confirm the validity of my results. Thanks for your time.
[image]

Comment: Please show said waveform!

Comment: No worries, I've attached the waveform.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude seems right to me, but the time should not be \$t_{off}\$, but \$\frac{1}{5} t_{on} \$ instead, because the demagnetization ends five time faster than the magnetization during the ON period (due to 5 times bigger reset voltage). After that there is no magnetizing current, the diode D3 stops conducting and the voltage stays zero across the windings.